# Microsoft SQL Server: Master Account Disabled

Tags: sql-server, account

for some reason, i disabled my master account at sql management studio. now, all i have is NAME-PC/SQLEXPRESS account.... please help me on how to actually recover my master account since i cant create my database and REINSTALLATION of MSSQL isnt an option :(